# Замена страниц через ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на ссылку, старая страница не убиралась (т.е. не появлялась белая область), пока новая страница не подгрузится. Что-то на подобие ВК

Comment: [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

Answer (score 2):

Дык AJAX используй и всё..

В любом ajax-запросе (ну если через jQuery), есть callback, в котором производятся действия после получения ответа от сервера..  Вот и пользуйся этим..